# Trying to implement jQuery in wordpress custom page for search autocomplete but is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

***Hi everybody, i just started developing website and i new to wordpress,php,mysql,jquery, hopefully someone can kind enough to help me solve the below problem which i have tried to resolve for months, thank you***

**-Objective**:To enable users to type in job title in a search box and search box would auto populate similar job titles from database in drop down just like google search

**-Problem:** Drop down for similar jobs are not shown

**-Environment:** Custom page on Wordpress,XAMPP,php,html,MYSQL database name 'jobsdatabase'

**-Developer's programming competency:** Beginner, just started developing website for 5 months, have tried to solve this problem for 6 weeks

**- Relevant Files and location:**

1. C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php
2. C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\page_search_job_form V6.php
3. C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\functions.php

   ***page_search_job_form V6.php***

   ```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {  

    jQuery('#searchform_jobtitle').keyup(ajaxsubmit);


    function ajaxsubmit()
    {

         var searchform_jobtitle = jQuery(this).serialize(); 



               jQuery.ajax(
               { 
                   url:'/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  
                   //my admin-ajax.php folder directory is C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php, 
                   //i have also tried using "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" but it is not working
                   method:"POST",  
                   action:"searchform_jobtitle",
                   // i have tried using data:"searchform_jobtitle" as well but it is not working
                   success:function(data)
                   {               
                   jQuery("#jobtitle").fadeIn();  
                   jQuery("#jobtitle").html(data);  
                   },
                   error: function(errorThrown)
                   {
                   alert(errorThrown);
                   }

               });
   }
   });

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>  

       <form action="/" form type="post" id="searchform_jobtitle" style="width:500px;">
       <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search...">
       </form>
       <div id="jobtitle"></div>


   </body>
   ```

***functions.php***

```
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_searchform_jobtitle','searchform_jobtitle');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_searchform_jobtitle','searchform_jobtitle');

function searchform_jobtitle()
{

    $searchform_jobtitle = ucfirst($_POST["action"]);

    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');


    if(!$con)
    {
        echo 'Not connected to server';
        $con->print_error();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'connected to server';
    }   

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'jobsdatabase'))
    {
        echo 'Database not selected';
        $con->print_error();

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Database selected';
    }   

     if(isset($_POST["action"])) 
    {  

        $query = "SELECT * FROM job_info WHERE job_title like '%".$_post["action"]."%'"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  

      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                $output .= '<li>'.$row["job_title"].'</li>'; 

           }  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $output .= '<li>Job Not Found</li>';  
      }  


        echo $output;  

    mysqli_close($con);
 die();

}   

?>
```

```html
Data in Mysql DB job_info as below:
job_title 
---------- 
IT project manager
Business analyst
programmer 
cleaner 
house cleaner
```

Answer (score 0):

So for this, I put the id "searchform_jobtitle" on the input itself, as your JS sends AJAX on keyup it doesn't need a form.

Next up, here's the AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:'test.php',
    method:"POST",
    data: {
        search: $('#searchform_jobtitle').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);             
        $("#jobtitle").fadeIn();  
        $("#jobtitle").html(data);  
    },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Sending an object in the data section so I know for sure that the value in the input is being posted as the value for $_POST['search'], but you can do whatever you like with that.

Now my PHP is just a simple test:

```
$searchform_jobtitle = ucfirst($_POST["search"]);
echo $searchform_jobtitle;
```

Which shows that it works. For your code, you're going to want to decide how you want it to work, as this isn't going to know how to evoke your particular method, something like this should work:

```
if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
    jobTitleSearch();
}

function jobTitleSearch() {
    $searchform_jobtitle = ucfirst($_POST["search"]);
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Hi Maytch, thank you for your response. As per your advice, i have added input id="searchform_jobtitle" and amend the "URL" at my jQuery to point to the directory, i am getting response from mysql unfortunately the response is not as expected.The mysql keeps returning all rows of DB entries

Comment: I have actually tried using your code " data: {
        search: $('#searchform_jobtitle').val()
    }, but mysql keep responding with 0

Comment: I have also tried a few other changes for the past week but still aint working, please help, thank you

Comment: I have actually tried adding if (searchform_jobtitle.length >= 3) before   jQuery.ajax in page_search_job_form V6.php but also not working